# How to find EPStatements associated with UpdateListener

Tags: java, esper

I was wondering if Esper provides a mechanism to discover all [EPStatement](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/api/com/espertech/esper/client/EPStatement.html) objects that an [UpdateListener](http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.11.0/doc/api/com/espertech/esper/client/UpdateListener.html) interface implementation is associated with.

The association between EPStatement and UpdateListener is one-way (from EPStatement to UpdateListener) and I cannot see in the API or reference docs if there's a way to discover EPstatement object(s) for a given UpdateListener or would I have to maintain such tracking myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no association from UpdateListener to Statement unless you create one which would be easy.